# How to do PHP prepend or include file to all files in dir?

Tags: php

For example, we have a directory with php files.

And in this folder we have a file `class.logger.inc`

Before executing files from dir, we need to 'prepend' or include automatically this file, to call functions from class.logger from other php files in directory.

How to realize it not touching files.

Looked at the `auto_prepend_file` but seems it include if script terminate with `exit()`

Comment: besides `auto_prepend_file` core ini configuration, you might want to develop an application with a structure allowing you to post- or pre-run methods. Like EventManager, ServiceManager with AwareInterface, ... many possibilities, too long to explain in a single answer.

Comment: I think you should be looking at [PHP Autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: @DanFromGermany i know about this)). i have a working project, dont have to touch files. only `prepend` before php file will run.

Comment: "include if script terminat with exit?" it's PREPENDING the files, which means they're auto-included as the file is loaded/parsed. whether they exit/die later on in irrelent. the prepend occurs during startup.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using URL rewriting,

in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^originaldirectory/(.*)$ /wrapper.php?f=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and the content of the wrapper file should be

```
<?php
include 'prepended_content.php';
include 'originaldirectory/'.$_GET['f'];
include 'appended_content.php';
?>
```